# using img in html code. But how come the image does not show? but instead a little file shows

Tags: image

I'm using the mimo code app for coding. I saved a picture from google in the folder "Saved Pictures". The file name is "generic background". I did the code <="/Saved Pictures/generic background.jpg">. But the image does not show. Instead what shows is a small file. Don't really know how to get the image to show. I did used img src before =, but I need 10 reputations points to post an image even though I was just trying to show the code.

Comment: Did you forgot to include server path? If you copy the url in the browser and hit enter are you able to see the image?

You can also include a picture from google simply by copying the link of the image.
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9a/Gull_portrait_ca_usa.jpg"/>

Comment: I used a couple server paths such as "/Saved Pictures/generic background.jpg", .. /Saved Pictures/generic background.jpg", "generic background.jpg". I am able to see the image when I copy the url in browser. The image does show when I copy and paste the url in the code.